# How to fix this the problem of non-recovery of an entity by the ID?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to recover a user from his id and for that I wrote the following code but the test with postman returns errors 500. I put you an image of the error.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juh53.jpg)

```
//Recuperer un utilisateur
@GetMapping("/getUser/{id}")
public ResponseEntity findUserById(@PathVariable(name="id") Integer id) {
    if(id == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Impossible d'afficher un utilisateur avec un id null");
    }

    User user = userRepository.getOne(id);

    if(user == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(user);
}
```

Comment: You should edit the stack trace into your post. The image link will eventually expire, leaving little context for users having a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data is not found the table, `findOne` will return null, whereas `getOne()` will throw javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException. 
So I think wrong method using here, try `findById(id)` instead of `getOne(id)`.

Answer (score 0):

`userRepository.getOne(id)` throws an exception. So the line `ResponseEntity.notFound().build();` is never executed.

Try to use a try/catch.

Alternatively, you can use `findById(id)` instead of `getOne(id)`. It returns null instead of throwing an exception.